# Can I use same python API for H2O-3 in pySparkling for Sparkling Water?

Tags: h2o

I am new to H2o ai and I have tried few things using python api. It looks good to me. I know spark and I am very much interested in Sparkling Water. So my question is - In pySparkling, Can I use same python API applied for H2o ai ptatfom ?

Answer (score 0):

YES..

As per pySparkling document I find :

PySparkling is an integration of Python with Sparkling Water. It allows user to start H2O services on a Spark cluster from Python API.

In the PySparkling driver program, the Spark Context, which uses Py4J to start the driver JVM and the Java Spark Context, is used to create the H2O Context (hc). That in turn starts an H2O cloud (cluster) in the Spark ecosystem. **Once the H2O cluster is up, the H2O Python package is used to interact with it and run H2O algorithms.** All pure H2O calls are executed via H2O’s REST API interface. Users can easily integrate their regular PySpark workflow with H2O algorithms using PySparkling.